# Completely disable some keys on a keyboard in windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

With AutoHotKey or with the PowerToys keyboard filter I disable lets say <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>. Copy & paste etc won't work, but <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> will still bring up the screen that offers the task manager and account options. How could I **really** disable these keys with all of their imaginable shortcuts?

I have a VIA keyboard and on that, when I assign nothing, it is really nothing, but unfortunately VIA is not an option for this use case. Neither is physically removing the keys, because those keys should be easily restorable.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-disable-ctrlaltdel-login/6a2b7375-30e4-4a64-9096-a159eb0d0a41

Comment: Have you tried this: [Sharpkeys](https://www.randyrants.com/2022/04/sharpkeys-3-9-4/) available free on [Microsoft Store > sharpkeys](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/sharpkeys/XPFFCG7M673D4F) as well as [Github > sharpkeys](http://www.github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys).  I am not affiliated.

Comment: @user3419297 this deals with exactly one keybinding. I fathom there are many more like this.

Comment: SharpKeys as @BlindSpots points out is a good way to change them.  I myself do it by  hand via the registry.. but that is only because I didn't know that Sharpkeys existed.  [Here is info](https://isenselabs.com/posts/keyboard-key-kills-and-remaps-for-windows-users) on how the registry key works (and sharpkeys too).

Comment: so we ended up "cheating" and got a VIA keyboard for our purposes where you can disable keys on the firmware level